# Looking for a updateable & secure WebBrowser-Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control

I would like to implement a web browser in my c#-program. The browser should cover some requirements:

- It should be updateable
  I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be great if the implementet web-browser would alwasy be using the latest version of the based browser which is installed on the system.
- Easy implementation
  Of course, the easier to use, the better!
- Security
  And the used browser should be as secure as possible. The safest i could think of, was running the browser in sandboxed mode. Are there other possibilities to achieve a maxiumum of security?

Untill now i have found some wrappers for different Browser-Engines, but none of hem seems to match my requirements:

- Awesomium: Is very easy to use! But is still based on an old Version of Chrome (12.0.702.0)
- Berkelium: Same as Awesomium, i think.
- CefSharp:
- GeckoFX: Needs FireFox 1.5 installed
- MozNet: Based on FireFox 3.6
- WebKit.NET: I'm not sure about that...
- the native WebBrowser Class: I think this is the best i could get - because it always uses the latest installed version of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, i think i'll stick with the WebBrowser Control. It's not perfect and the posibilities to use own settings are not as good as i hoped, but i think since there seems no better solution, it will have to work...